# Default thread pool in tomcat of a spring boot application

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat, threadpool

In a spring boot application or in generally, does tomcat has a default thread pool configured?

If we do not configure anything, the tomcat will initiate new threads for each request and the thread gets destroy once the request finish?

And if a thread pool configured, particular thread would serve many requests when ever container pick that thread from pool?

Answer (score 10):

Here is the configs of the embed Tomcat in springboot

```sh
server.tomcat.accept-count=100 # Maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use.
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=true # Whether to buffer output such that it is flushed only periodically.
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=logs # Directory in which log files are created. Can be absolute or relative to the Tomcat base dir.
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=false # Enable access log.
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd # Date format to place in the log file name.
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=common # Format pattern for access logs.
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log # Log file name prefix.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rename-on-rotate=false # Whether to defer inclusion of the date stamp in the file name until rotate time.
server.tomcat.accesslog.request-attributes-enabled=false # Set request attributes for the IP address, Hostname, protocol, and port used for the request.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true # Whether to enable access log rotation.
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log # Log file name suffix.
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns= # Comma-separated list of additional patterns that match jars to ignore for TLD scanning.
server.tomcat.background-processor-delay=10s # Delay between the invocation of backgroundProcess methods. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
server.tomcat.basedir= # Tomcat base directory. If not specified, a temporary directory is used.
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=10\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        192\\.168\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        127\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.1[6-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.2[0-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.3[0-1]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\
        0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1\\
        ::1 # Regular expression that matches proxies that are to be trusted.
server.tomcat.max-connections=10000 # Maximum number of connections that the server accepts and processes at any given time.
server.tomcat.max-http-header-size=0 # Maximum size in bytes of the HTTP message header.
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2097152 # Maximum size in bytes of the HTTP post content.
server.tomcat.max-threads=200 # Maximum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=10 # Minimum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.port-header=X-Forwarded-Port # Name of the HTTP header used to override the original port value.
server.tomcat.protocol-header= # Header that holds the incoming protocol, usually named "X-Forwarded-Proto".
server.tomcat.protocol-header-https-value=https # Value of the protocol header indicating whether the incoming request uses SSL.
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=true # Whether requests to the context root should be redirected by appending a / to the path.
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header= # Name of the HTTP header from which the remote IP is extracted. For instance, `X-FORWARDED-FOR`.
server.tomcat.resource.cache-ttl= # Time-to-live of the static resource cache.
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8 # Character encoding to use to decode the URI.
server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects= # Whether HTTP 1.1 and later location headers generated by a call to sendRedirect will use relative or absolute redirects.
```

As you can see for the default value, the minimum amount of worker threads is `10`, and the maximum amount of worker threads is `200`, and the maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use is `100`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes spring boot uses Embeded tomcat server, you can modify some of its configs in `application.yml` or `application.properties` By default it has 200 threads [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

```
# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties)
server.port=8080
server.address= # bind to a specific NIC
server.session-timeout= # session timeout in seconds
server.context-path= # the context path, defaults to '/'
server.servlet-path= # the servlet path, defaults to '/'
server.tomcat.access-log-pattern= # log pattern of the access log
server.tomcat.access-log-enabled=false # is access logging enabled
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto # ssl forward headers
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.basedir=/tmp # base dir (usually not needed, defaults to tmp)
server.tomcat.background-processor-delay=30; # in seconds
server.tomcat.max-threads = 0 # number of threads in protocol handler
server.tomcat.uri-encoding = UTF-8 # character encoding to use for URL decoding
```

Comment: but is it really a pool? it indicates maximum concurrent request it can handle is 200 right? And after a thread served a request, that thread would no longer available know?

Comment: It's pool of threads, you can log the thread name 'Thread.currentThread().getName()' then you will see 'http-nio-1' , 'http-nio-2' like this

Comment: I tried increasing it like this: server.tomcat.max-threads = 400 but it is still only using 200 threads max, also If I set server.tomcat.max-threads = 15 it keeps using 200, any clues?  In the same file (application.properties) I did a server.port = newPort number and it is taking that config... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

From Spring boot 2.3 onwards , the configuration is changed to server.tomcat.threads.max
For setting value as 400, add below in your application.properties :

server.tomcat.threads.max=400